# Second hotkey after the first is not working using pyautogui in Python

Tags: python, hotkeys

I'm using Python 3.6 on Windows 7 64bit. It worked once but after it's not working. I tried it in several versions, but the result is the same. anyone know how to fix this?

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c') # ctrl-c to copy
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v') # ctrl-v to paste
```

Comment: what exactly is not working? Some thoughts: pyautogui does not automatically wait, you usually have to put some `sleep()` calls to make things work. Also how do you run this? running it from a terminal, for me, sends the ctrl+c to the terminal immediately, which is quite different from a 'copy' as it quits the current program.

Answer (score 0):

`Pyautogui` isn't the best python library out there for hotkeys. I would recommend using either `keyboard` or `pynput`. Here's an example with `keyboard` (you just need to use the + operator):

```
import keyboard

keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+c') #copy
keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+v') #paste
```